# Wake up Adafruit Feather 32u4 from sleep mode with external interrupt

Tags: c, arduino, sleep, interrupt, adafruit

I have an Adafruit Feather ATMega 32u4. I want to put it into sleep mode and wake it up with pressing a switch as an external interrupt. This is what I tried so far and which worked:

- switching a LED on and off with the switch
- putting the Adafruit to sleep and let it wake up with a watchdog timer.

I tried to combine the code examples that I found in the Internet to make the code fit my board. I manage to put it to sleep but then I have to reset it because the Interrupt doesn't work. I would be very happy for any help and please don't blame me, I am a complete beginner!
Here is my code:

```
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <avr/power.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

int pin2 = 2;

void pin2Interrupt(void) {
    /* This will bring us back from sleep. */

    detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2));
}


void enterSleep(void) {
    /* Setup pin2 as an interrupt and attach handler. */

    delay(100);
    set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);  
    sleep_enable();

    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), pin2Interrupt, RISING);

    if (digitalRead(pin2)){
        sleep_mode();
    }

    /* The program will continue from here  
     * First thing to do is disable sleep.
     */

    sleep_disable(); 
}


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    /* Setup the pin direction. */
    pinMode(pin2, INPUT_PULLUP);

    Serial.println("Initialisation complete.");
}

int seconds = 0;

void loop() {
    delay(1000);
    seconds++;

    Serial.print("Awake for ");
    Serial.print(seconds, DEC);
    Serial.println(" second");

    if(seconds == 3){
        Serial.println("Entering sleep");
        delay(200);
        seconds = 0;
        enterSleep();
    }
}
```

Update:

```
#include "LowPower.h"
#include "avr/interrupt.h"
#define BUTTON 3
#define LEDPIN 13

void wakeUp() {
  detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(BUTTON));
}

void Blink(byte ledPin, int msDelay, byte loops) {
  for (byte i=0; i<loops; i++) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    delay(msDelay);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    delay(msDelay);
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(BUTTON, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(BUTTON, LOW);
  pinMode(LEDPIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  cli();

  EIMSK &= ~(1 << INT0);
  EICRA |= (1 << ISC01) | (1 << ISC00);
  EIMSK |= (1 << INT0);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(BUTTON), wakeUp, CHANGE);
  sei();
  LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_FOREVER, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF);
  Blink(LEDPIN, 100, 3);
  Serial.println("AWAKE!");
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: maybe attach the interrupt before sleep, not after

Comment: it goes to sleep at the point "sleep_mode();", so the function attachInterrupt is right before it. set_sleep_mode and sleep_enable only gives the uController information but doesn't put it to sleep, yet, if I understood it correctly

Comment: Are interrupts enabled?

Comment: I just gave a code update.
I enabled global and external interrupts but the Adafruit does still not wake up.